# NSCursor appears in black and white

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grayscale, nsimage

I'm trying to display a cursor using the following code:

```
// imageData is the raw data pointer from the file (uint8_t* vector)
NSData* o_imageData = [ NSData dataWithBytes:imageData.begin() length:imageData.size() ];
NSImage* o_image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData: o_imageData];

// Hotspot is extracted earlier on
cursor_ = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage:o_image hotSpot:o_hotspot];
```

Now, when I set this cursor as the current, it displays the cursor in greyscale. It's something, but I rather have it in colour (as is the original image). The cursor image is encoded within a .cur file (Win32 standard cursor format, very similar to .ico format). On Win32 the cursor is displayed properly and in colour and when I load a cursor from a file it works fine too, but initialising the image with raw data seems to initialise it wrong.
Could this have something to do with the image representation? And if so, how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Sounds like you're getting the alpha and maybe one other channel. Regardless it's not a native format and you should really get an image file that is either PDF with vector art in it or one of TIFF or PNG with various sizes to ensure you cover accessibility as well as retina displays.

Comment: The CUR (ICO) format actually supports multiple resolution images in one file, it also has header info for cursor hotspot and widely available in cursor packages, which makes it a handy format in my opinion. Internally the image is just a BMP or PNG.

Comment: Still you may need to either change the wrapper or drop down to writing some code that lets NSImage know that or see if another API can get it into a form NSIMAGE understands